# Exception handling in Windows 8. Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm getting an exception when I get some strange json values from my datasource and I want to analyze that or handle it so the application doesn't crash. Here is the code:

```
private async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        //if (this._table.Count != 0) return;

        this.Table.Clear();
        var jsonObject = await DownloadSpreadsheet.GetJson();
        for (int row = 0; row < jsonObject["rows"].Count(); row++)
        {
            try
            {
                Table table = new Table();

                table.Day = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][0]["v"].ToString();

                table.Month = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][1]["v"].ToString();
                table.Year = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][2]["v"].ToString();
                table.People = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][4]["v"].ToString();


                this.Table.Add(table);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }

    }
```

How can I write out this Exception ex ? Can't use messagedialog inside catch clause as it doesn't support "await". Could anyone help out with this or show some examples of such code... I can't seem to google it out to reference it to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to handle the exception gracefully, just write it to a log file in the catch statement and move on without re-throwing. Then you can analyze the log file at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
String errorMessage = null;
try
{
  await DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  errorMessage = ex.Message;
}
if (errorMessage != null)
{
  await new MessageDialog(errorMessage).ShowAsync();
}
```